# Index CVS categorical fields as INT maps

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, mapping, pca

GOAL: read in CSVs and map Str fields to integer indices.
Language: Python 3.x

If a column is not float-cast-able, map its unique values to a Dict whose values are the index.
 (ROW 3 = "Help", "Me", "Tom Cruise", "Help")
 MapRow3 = {Help: 0, Me: 1, Tom Cruise: 2}

---

When I run the code, it always hits the "Except". I tried skipping the first line (labels) when reading in the file but that didn't work, either. I assume I'm doing the casting incorrectly.

```
def makePlot(filename):
reader = np.loadtxt(filename, dtype=str, delimiter=',')
reader = reader.T #transpose matrix so columns become rows


for row in reader:
    try:
        reader[row] = list(float(reader[row])) #it always skips this line
    except:
        myset = set(row) #I'd rather this be a dict as described above
```

Comment: Please try to limit your question to one particular issue. As it stands it is not entirely clear what you want answered

Comment: Welcome to SO.  `edit` to separate this post to a single question, then ask additional questions as needed. Each question should be specific to a single problem. SO questions are more helpful to users visitors in that way, and it's less overwhelming to answer.  Left as is, SO may close this question as "too broad".

Comment: What's `np.loadtxt()`?